# Asp.NET MVC 4 Entity Framework 5 - Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, database-first

I'm developing Asp.NET MVC 4 web application. I'm trying to connect to my database "Test" through Entity Framework Client. I've added EntityFramework reference to project and I'm using MSSQL.
From unknown reason, I'm getting the following error:
*Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.*

Did anyone have similar problem?

Settings in web.config are:

```
<configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</configSections>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/TestEDM.csdl|res://*/TestEDM.ssdl|res://*/TestEDM.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=MARINA-PC\MSSQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
```

Error occurs at this line in *InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute* class:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("TestEntities", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

This is a stacktrace:

```
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
   at WebMatrix.Data.DbProviderFactoryWrapper.CreateConnection(String connectionString)
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.<>c__DisplayClass15.<OpenConnectionStringInternal>b__14()
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.get_Connection()
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.EnsureConnectionOpen()
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.<QueryInternal>d__0.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at WebMatrix.Data.Database.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] args)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.DatabaseWrapper.QuerySingle(String commandText, Object[] parameters)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CheckTableExists(IDatabase db, String tableName)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.CreateTablesIfNeeded()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeMembershipProvider(SimpleMembershipProvider simpleMembership, DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean createTables)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeProviders(DatabaseConnectionInfo connect, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables)
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(String connectionStringName, String userTableName, String userIdColumn, String userNameColumn, Boolean autoCreateTables)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try installing [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876).

Comment: Hi Jakub, hm...i'm not sure how this will help me. One day i will have to migrate application to MS SQL (non Compact version) so the problem still remains...